# UIViewController's editButtonItem not changing with swipe to delete

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, editing

I use `UIViewController`'s `editButtonItem` to control edit mode on my table view.

The problem is that in most apps, when you swipe a row to delete the element, that edit button changes to "Done" state. That way the user can tap "Done" to stop deleting elements.

*Done button in a swipe to delete situation*

[image]

*It doesn't do this in my app*

[image]

I guess I could change the title and style of the edit button in `tableview:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:`, but isn't the point of `UIViewController`'s `editButtonItem` to be automatic?

Thanks.

Comment: The done button changes it's state when the table view goes to editing mode. Have you tried to press the edit button? Does the button change then?

Comment: @dasdom Yes, it does change for a full edit. I'm asking when I edit a single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing these two delegate methods solved it for me.
Setting the .editing property of the view controller to YES and back to NO.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.editing = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.editing = NO;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly right! I used `setEditing:animated:` with with `animated = YES`, it gives a better feel.

Answer (score 1):

It's only automatic when the `UIViewController`'s `.editing` property is YES. When you're only editing a single row, the view controller itself is not in editing mode, so it doesn't change the button.

Comment: I get that, but why that seems to be a standard in other apps to change to Done even for editing a single row?

Comment: Don't know. At least this way it gives you the option - the done button is kind of redundant when editing a single row because a tap anywhere else on the screen cancels the swipe to delete.

Comment: My point was more that you can still tap the edit button after swiping to delete, which doesn't really make sense.